# SocketException in a Signed Java Applet

Tags: java, security, ftp, firewall, signed-applet

I have a Java applet which is using the Apache commons.net API for FTP. I initially ran the applet without signing it, and it threw a

```
SocketException : Software caused connection abort
```

I looked this up online and found that my firewall was blocking my applet. So, to confirm this, I disabled my firewall and ran the applet. It worked fine.

Then, I followed the instructions given in another site to self-sign the applet using nnetbeans:

**Project Properties** -> **Enable Web start** -> **Self-sign using generated key**

Still, the same error persists. I can't find anything that explains this particular error.

Comment: Digitally signing an applet will not enable it to circumvent firewall security.

Comment: Then what can I do? Is there another way to get around this?